# how to set a list of stopwatch in android?

Tags: android, time, chronometer

I want to create an android list of stopwatch.

I intent that every stopwatch will start counting down 5 minutes after first click only.

I have had few questions:

1. I have tried to use chromometer, but it's counting time up (meaning starting at 00:00 even if I do:

   chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

   chronometer.start();

)

1. how do you suggest keeping the state of the chromometer?

a. if the application crashes? I need to save the state every time in the DB?

b. if the list items are recycled?